# Basic volume issue representation

Tags: c#, classes

I have the following `struct`:

```
public struct VolumeIssue
{
    public readonly string Volume;

    public readonly string Issue;

    public VolumeIssue(string volume, string issue)
    {
        this.Volume = volume;
        this.Issue = issue;
    }

    public bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace()
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Volume) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Issue);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder stringRep = new StringBuilder("");

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Volume))
        {
            stringRep.AppendFormat("v. {0}", this.Volume);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Issue))
            {
                stringRep.AppendFormat(" iss. {0}", this.Issue);
            }
        }

        return stringRep.ToString();
    }
}
```

Overall I am happy with it. But being still a relatively inexperienced developer, I would like some input on the design of this `struct`. Ideas on how to flesh it out are also greatly appreciated.

In order to add more context, here is one of the use cases:

```
public class IssueRangeCoverage
{
    public VolumeIssue Start { get; set; }

    public VolumeIssue End { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this.Start.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() && this.End.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            return "";
        }

        string endString = this.End.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(endString))
        {
            endString = "Current";
        }
        return this.Start.ToString() + " - " + endString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything that stands out in this.  It's fairly small and quite compact.  The only thing I might suggest is changing the public fields to properties.

```
public string Volume { get; private set; }

public string Issue { get; private set; }
```

This will ensure your implementation details of Volume and Issue are hidden as mentioned by @Hosch250.

Also, as this is an immutable struct both in it's definition of [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx) being a value type and the fact that you are only using these fields in the ToString().  Hence you could consider building the ToString() field up in the constructor thus saving you the task of checking on every ToString() method.

You might end up with something along the lines of:

```
public struct VolumeIssue
{
    public string Volume { get; private set; }

    public string Issue { get; private set; }

    private readonly string description;

    public VolumeIssue(string volume, string issue)
    {
        this.Volume = volume;
        this.Issue = issue;

        description = BuildDescription();
    }

    public bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace()
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Volume) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Issue);
    } 
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.description;
    }

    private string BuildDescription() 
    {
        StringBuilder stringRep = new StringBuilder("");

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Volume))
        {
            stringRep.AppendFormat("v. {0}", this.Volume);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Issue))
            {
                stringRep.AppendFormat(" iss. {0}", this.Issue);
            }
        }

        return stringRep.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what would be gained by that? Doesn't a field have a smaller footprint?

Comment: @Max  I'm not sure on that, but as properties are sort of methods themselves and just contain backing fields under the hood, I don't see how the footprint size would matter.  Unless ultimate optimization was your main goal?

Comment: Optimization was part of the goal, hence the choice of a struct over a class. Having only two methods plus a field supplied when using a property instead of simply one field sounds a little overdone to me

Comment: The idea of building the description in the ctor is great idea! Thanks!

Comment: @Max quick google search tells me properties take up no more room than fields.  However structs do take up a smaller memory footprint (by the size of the bytes it takes to store the class reference).  However classes are faster when being passed between methods.  Hence it depends on what optimizations you are looking for I guess.

Comment: `private readonly description;` should be `private readonly string description;` and in `ToString()` this `return _description;` should be `return description;`

Comment: see [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029188/auto-properties-and-structs) about using auto-implemented properties in a struct

Comment: @Max yes, that is even better as it really does enforce the mutability of the struct and removes any mistakes a programmer might make when adding to the class

Answer (score 7):

Figured I would raise a few points:

Having read your responses/replies, we can gather you have the following specs (roughly):

- Small memory footprint
- Optimization

Before I go over those two points, Let's first step through the code:

I feel the name `VolumeIssue` is not very descriptive. In fact, it seems odd to have the struct name be the combination of both of its fields.

Next, I would keep the `readonly` members but make them private, also drop the uppercase. Instead, use publicly accessible properties in order to access these fields as follows:

```
private readonly string volume;
public string Volume { get { return this.volume; } }
```

At this stage, you are most likey asking "why?" and probably for good reason. I mean, you have the following case covered:

- Immutability - You've exposed the fields but they are `readonly`

Why would you bother adding more code when the current solution gives you the same solution for less...or does it?

The code may be *functionally* equivalent, but we there are more things to be considered. The struct is `public`. This means that you are allowing other developers to interact/use/inspect and interface to your value type.

[Jon Skeet states the following](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx):

> For every type you write, you should consider its interface to the
>   rest of the world

You see, by exposing your fields, you are exposing the implementation of your struct, and I would recommend against this.

Jon goes on to say:

> A property communicates the idea of "I will make a value available to
>   you, or accept a value from you." It's not an implementation concept,
>   it's an interface concept.

Currently, you are violating the design principle of hiding the implementation and for this reason I would also argue in favouring the property/field combo. I've linked the article quotes at the bottom, it's a good read and should give you some interesting points to consider.

Having looked at you use of the `struct`, it is important to note that you only use the fields within the `struct` itself. Now, as these fields will only be given once (during the constructor), I would build the contents of the `ToString` method there and then as @dreza pointed out.

**Back to your use case**

I would say you are right in choosing to use a `struct`. Your struct only contains two fields and is embedded inside another object. See more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c).

Briefly back to the first two points:

**Memory footprint**

Yup, you've got this covered.

**Optimisation**

One key thing that should be pointed out is that your value type should implement `IEquatable`. I would always do this.
This way, you avoid the cost of boxing/unboxing your value type upon any equivalence comparison.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty good.  However, in this case, I would probably use a `class` instead of a `struct`:

```
public class VolumeIssue { ... }
```

Then, I would change these to private:

```
private string Volume;
private string Issue;
```

This ensures they cannot be accessed except by functions within the class.  Also, while `readonly` is perfectly fine, you don't really need that now because they cannot be accessed except by functions within the class.  Also, if you wish, you could provide a function to change the values, and only that function will be allowed to do so.  To be able to access these values, you could do something like this:

```
public string GetVolume()
{
    return Volume;
}

public string GetIssue()
{
    return Issue;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this produces quite the same result.  Especially the change in ToString() which will not append anything even if Volume is not null and Issue is.

Comment: @dreza is actually correct. It is possible for there to be a volume without an issue. In which case the original code would produce `v. 1` (which is the desired text), while your suggestion gives: `v. 1 iss.`

Comment: I've updated the question to add some more context

Comment: @Hosch250 I'm still not sure if that's correct.  Now when Volume is null you might still append an issue, which isn't the same as the OP's.